# current_user_can('Administrator') does not return true in multisite if user is Administrator but NOT Super Admin

Tags: multisite, admin

I have a multisite WordPress installation set up, and have a user who is set to an 'Administrator' role on both sites. However, the function `current_user_can('Administrator')` does not return true when logged in as them, which I expected it to.

My user account, however, is an 'Administrator' on both sites, and *also* a 'Super Admin' on the network, and the call returns true for me.

Why is this? Shouldn't the first user only be false if checking for 'Super Admin' and not just 'Administrator'?

If this is an issue, is there any other way that I can check if a user is set to the 'Administrator' role without being a 'Super Admin'?

Comment: `current_user_can()` should never be used for a role check, especially on a multisite. It is generally just not reliable enough. Be aware that `administrator` is just a **name**, it doesn't say anything about the real capabilities. Test for capabilities, not for roles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree that current_user_can('Administrator') should return true for the user. However, current_user_can is primarily intended to check for capabilities, which is generally a more robust check to be making.

I'd suggest something like this (untested):

```
if ( current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) && ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
//...
}
```

So this is checking if the current user can activate plugins but cannot update core. This should return true for Administrators whilst returning false for Network Admins - as on multisite update_core is reserved for Network Admins.

Comment: Even `activate_plugins` returned false, and I only now noticed that my admin user can't even edit plugins for the site that they are admin on, which seems strange. However, I did get this to idea to work using `delete_pages` instead. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, it's too early in the morning for me apparently.. `delete_pages` was far too open.. `list_users` is what I am using instead!

Answer (score 10):

There is a Typo in your expression use `current_user_can('administrator')` instead of `current_user_can('Administrator')` (a instead of A).

Comment: While is this true, the other answer is still more correct when considering good practice.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually answers the OP's question, regardless of good practice.